# Scala not resolving X as Y, even though X extends Y

Tags: scala, types, type-mismatch, traits, mismatch

[See snippet Below]
I read that I have a X which is a Piece, and I have a Player that requires a Piece. The player Me attempts to define this Piece with Piece X. Yet the Scala does not recognize X as a piece, rather it sees 'X.type'. What does X.type mean? I'm not exactly sure what my problem is so I'm having a hard time searching.

I don't see how this can be type shadowing [ See [Scala really weird Type Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090756/scala-really-weird-type-mismatch) ], since I don't specify another 'Piece', rather I only specify that I require a 'Piece'.

It seems like there is something preventing Scala to resolve X as a Piece.

To try in REPL

```
trait Piece { val piece: Char }
case class X extends Piece { val piece: Char = 'X' }

trait Player { val piece: Piece }
case class Me extends Player { val piece: Piece = X }
```

Result

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : X.type
 required: Piece
       case class Max extends Player { val piece: Piece = X }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because by X you're only describing a class (so it's actually a *type*), whereas Scala is expecting an *object* (or instance) of type Piece. You would get the same error by doing this in the first case:

```
case class X extends Piece { val piece: Char = Char }
```

As you can see, your version works because you pass a specific character, not a type. If you want your code to work, you probably have to create a new object and pass it in:

```
case class Me extends Player { val piece: Piece = new X }
```

EDIT: As the OP noted in the comment below, using X() also works, because as X is a case class it gets an implicit apply() method:

```
case class Me extends Player { val piece: Piece = X() }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I usually have a parameter so I never ran into this issue. Even using X() solves the issue. Didn't realize a class IS a type. Whoa now pattern matching makes even more sense, and the fact that classes are the blueprints to an instance is even more clear, awesome. It just clicked!

Comment: This answer isn't actually entirely correct. Could you update it to align with my answer?  Just in the interests of, you know, helpfulness.

Answer (score 2):

Case classes without parameters are deprecated. Use `case class X()` and `case class Me()` instead. That way you will have to create object of `X` class with `X()` call, as is described in other answers.

Alternatively you can use `case object`s:

```
case object X extends Piece { val piece: Char = 'X' }.
```

In fact, if you use case object here, your code will start to work:

```
case class Me extends Player { val piece: Piece = X }  // Works fine
```

It depends on your requirements though. It is possible that you need multiple instances of `X`; then case object is not for you.

Comment: Thanks for this! Clears up why REPL complained about deprecation. Do you use case objects over case classes whenever you only need once instance of that object? I notice that if you use case objects you can't pattern match like `case(x: X) => println("I am X")`, since 'X' is no longer a type but a reference to the 'X' object instead. Where I guess in this case you would check with something like `if (x == X) println("X thanks you")`

Comment: You can match, use `case X => println("I am X")`

Comment: @Miles, no, `if` is not needed. You can match directly, like `case X => ...`. I'm writing this because it is likely that you haven't got notification about sourcedelica's comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `case class X`, you're also creating a companion `object X`, which has a member `apply` that lets you say `X()`.  All this is obvious after some experience with Scala.

`X.type` is the singleton type of the object X.  It has nothing to do with "assigning a type", as the other answers put it.

When you say `X` as a value, it means that object. It is a term (i.e. value), not a type.

To create a new X, everyone writes `X()`, which is exactly `X.apply()`, and never `new X()`. Never?  Yeah, pretty much never.

Note that paramless case classes are long since deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I don't think you can "assign a type" unless you do something like `type Cool = List[Int]` where you create a new type 'Cool' which is a List[Int] right?

Comment: Technically you are not creating a new type in that case - `Cool` is a type alias - meaning it is exactly the same as `List[Int]`.  Creating a new type would mean `class Cool extends List[Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the type `X` to the variable `piece`, rather than an instance of `X`.